# Can't make UIToolBar black color with white button item tint (ios 9, Swift)

Tags: swift, ios9, xcode7, uitoolbar

I'm programmatically adding a toolbar to a UIPickerView so that I can have a "Done" button, and I want to make the UIToolBar black and the bar items white. The doc says that if you want an opaque UIToolBar, you have to set its translucency to false and set barStyle to black. I've done this and the UIToolBar remains white.

```
private func pickerViewSetup() {

    let pickerView = UIPickerView()
    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.dataSource = self
    pickerView.backgroundColor = .whiteColor()
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = true

    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.translucent = false
    toolBar.barStyle = .Black

    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "donePicker")
    doneButton.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    let flexibleSpaceItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .FlexibleSpace, target: self, action: "Flexible Space")

    toolBar.setItems([flexibleSpaceItem, doneButton], animated: false)
    toolBar.userInteractionEnabled = true

    pickerTextField.inputView = pickerView
    pickerTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Thanks u84six's answer. You can do like this:

```
toolBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()//"Done" button colour
toolBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()// bar background colour 
toolBar.sizeToFit()// Very important, the barTintColor will not work without this
```

Answer (score 5):

All I needed to do is add the call toolBar.sizeToFit() and that fixed all the color issues. Here's the complete working code:

```
private func pickerViewSetup() {

    let pickerView = UIPickerView()
    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.dataSource = self
    pickerView.backgroundColor = .whiteColor()
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = true

    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
    toolBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    toolBar.sizeToFit()

    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "donePicker")
    let flexibleSpaceItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .FlexibleSpace, target: self, action: "Flexible Space")

    toolBar.setItems([flexibleSpaceItem, doneButton], animated: false)
    toolBar.userInteractionEnabled = true

    pickerTextField.inputView = pickerView
    pickerTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
}
```

Comment: call `sizeToFit()` is so implicitly!!

Comment: Just for future devs, if your `UIBarButtonItem` is not clickable, then this is solution. `sizeToFit()` fixed also this problem I had.

Answer (score 0):

The `toolBar` is not of the desired color because `toolBar.backgroundColor` is not properly set. Set it to `BlackColor` with

```
toolBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.BlackColor()
```

Comment: @SergueiFedorov this is exactly what will solve the user's problem, so it is the only answer and **it is the answer**

Comment: Simply setting the background color did not work for me. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not enough. Add

```
toolBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.BlackColor();
```

Comment: That didn't change anything. Still white.